# node.js app: home '/' route works but not the other routes (and styles.css as well)

Tags: css, node.js, express, routes

I am learning nodejs and deployment. On localhost, that simple app works fine but when I deployed on a server only the home route ('/') is working. The other routes i.e. ('/blogs', '/blogs/create', etc.) do not work. And my css file also is not rendering.

The error message is:
*Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

I suspected the problem's with path or a simple typo, googled for a few days, tried various suggestions but failed to find any solution.

link: http://kindwood.wwwsg1-ss15.a2hosted.com/
My code for index.ejs, nav.ejs, head.ejs and app.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%- include('./partials/head') %>
<body>
  <%- include('./partials/nav') %>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class='heading'>Blogs</h2>
    <% blogs.forEach(blog=>{ %>
       <h3 class='title'><a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>"><%= blog.title %></a></h3>
       <p><%= blog.text %></p>
    <% }) %>        
    <%- include('./partials/footer') %>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<nav>
 <h1>blogs</h1>
 <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="/blogs">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blogs/create">create</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

---

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Blogs | <%= title %></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
```

---

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const Blog=require('./models/blog')

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://dave:test1234@cluster0.z2g3z.mongodb.net/nodetuts?retryWrites=true&w=majority',{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})

app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  Blog.find({})
  .then(blogs=>{
    // console.log(blogs)
    res.render('index',{blogs,title:'Homepage'})
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
app.get('/blogs',(req,res)=>{
  res.redirect('/')
})
app.post('/blogs',(req,res)=>{
  const blog=new Blog(req.body)
  blog.save()
  .then(blog=>{
    res.redirect('/blogs')
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
app.get('/blogs/create',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('create',{title:'Create'})
})
app.get('/blogs/:id',(req,res)=>{
  Blog.findById(req.params.id)
  .then(blog=>{
    res.render('details',{blog,title:'Details'})
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
app.delete('/blogs/:id',(req,res)=>{
  Blog.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id)
  .then(result=>{
    res.json({redirect:'/blogs'})   
  })
  .catch(err=>console.log(err))
})
app.get('/about',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('about',{title:'About'})
})
app.use((req,res)=>{
  res.render('404',{title:'404'})
})


app.listen(()=>console.log('server is listening'))
```

---

Comment: What happens if you start up your server and try the `/about` route first (without trying to fetch `/` first)?

Comment: probable forgot "exact"

Comment: Trying the /about route first gives the same error message.

Comment: forgot "exact"? Where would that be in the code please?

Comment: The 404 error message you posted sounds like it comes from an Apache DocumentRoot configuration. If anything you want Apache as a Reverse-Proxy in front of a seperate NodeJS process.

Comment: As I said before, I am learning webdev and, after reviewing the last reply (from Tobias K) and googling for a while, it would seem to me that deploying a node.js app is not as simple: it needs a front end server to proxy requests to a node.js server. Am I correct?

Comment: This is the reply from my web hosting customer service: "our shared servers use the Node.js plugin which should make the process of deploying the application easier for the clients. Node.js plugin work with Apache and LiteSpeed web server and doesn't require installing Nginx. ". If there is no need for a proxy server, is it a problem of port number?

Comment: Normally yes, imo you need a nodejs and a proxy server. I never tried webserver plugins for it, and would assume they may not work properly with routing done in index.js.